How can I make this running balance more granular in Google Sheets using MAP and LAMBDA?
This is the scenario:

The formula in column G is ={"Running Balance";map(A3:A8;B3:B8;C3:C8;D3:D8;E3:E8;lambda(Σ;Λ;Γ;ξ;Ξ;if(Σ="";;max(0;sumifs(E3:Ξ;D3:ξ;ξ;A3:Σ;Σ;B3:Λ;Λ)-Γ))))}
but it is not yielding the same result as it should in column H
Here is the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing
How can I proceed?

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

The formula returns the correct value based on the following logic:

SUM Column E for the current and previous rows where all of the Columns A, B, and D match the current row's.
From the result of #1, subtract the current row's column C, and return the MAX of 0 or that value.

Since all values match save A3 and A4, you should expect the same result of 0 from both rows.
If you change the two Product names to match you will get the desired result.
